# Strip out C Style Multi-line Comments

Tags: c#, regex, comments

I have a C# string object that contains the code of a generic method, preceded by some standard C-Style multi-line comments.

I figured I could use `System.Text.RegularExpressions` to remove the comment block, but I can seem to be able to get it to work.

I tried:

```
code = Regex.Replace(code,@"/\*.*?\*/","");
```

Can I be pointed in the right direction?

Comment: +1 for asking the question in a smart way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a RegexOptions.Multiline option parameter.

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

Full example

```
string input = @"this is some stuff right here
    /* blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah */ and this is more stuff
    right here.";

string pattern = @"/[*][\w\d\s]+[*]/";

string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.Multiline);
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using backslashes to escape `*` in the regex, but you also need to escape those backslashes in the C# string.

Thus, `@"/\*.*?\*/"` or `"/\\*.*?\\*/"`

Also,  a comment should be replaced with a whitespace, not the empty string, unless you are sure about your input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your backslashes before the stars.

```
string str = "hi /* hello */ hi";
str = Regex.Replace(str, "/\\*.*?\\*/", " ");
//str == "hi  hi"
```

Comment: I used the verbatim operator @, without it, I got compile errors

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
/\/\*.*?\*\//
```

Since there are some / in the regex, its better to use a different delimiter as:

```
#/\*.*?\*/#
```