# Regular expression to find and remove comments in CSS

Tags: c#, regex

I'm writing my own minifying tool for practice (regular expresssions practice), but after a few tutorials I'm still not getting it.

For example I'm trying to find and remove all comments from my CSS file and that includes:

1. Single line comments as in

   /** single line comment **********/ or

   /*************single line comment **/ and
2. Multi line comments as in

   /********** start of comment

   .myCssClass

   {

   ```
   font:13pt Arial;
   ```

   }

************* *end of comment ***/

So far I'm using an expression which can only deal with single line comments as follows

```
(\/\*.*\*\/)
```

But what I'm trying to understand about regular expressions is how do I tell the regex engine to span lines as well. I did try this:

```
(\/\*[.\n]*\*\/)
```

which doesn't work at all.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,
Jacques

Comment: Typically when you read in a file line-by-line you don't use a regex to span multiple lines.  For this you would regex the start of a comment and keep reading in lines to omit until you reach the end comment regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're running the match in C#, have you tried RegexOptions?

```
Match m = Regex.Match(word, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

"Multiline mode. Changes the meaning of ^ and $ so they match at the beginning and end, respectively, of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string."

Also see [Strip out C Style Multi-line Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538279/strip-out-c-style-multi-line-comments)

**EDIT:**

OK..looks like an issue w/ the regex.  Here is a working example using the regex pattern from http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html. This guy does a good job deriving the regex, and demonstrating the pitfalls and deficiencies of various approaches.  Note: RegexOptions.Multiline/RegexOptions.Singleline does not appear to affect the result.

```
string input = @"this is some stuff right here
    /* blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah 
    blah blah blah */ and this is more stuff /* blah */
    right here.";

string pattern = @"(/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/)";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, string.Empty, RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: thanks for the input. I'm using the multiline option yes, which has certainly helped for one or two other items.

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression which matches C-style comments (which begin with `/*`, end with `*/` and do not nest) is:

```
[/][*]([^*]|[*]*[^*/])*[*]+[/]
```

(I have a little write up about the derivation of this. See: www.nongnu.org/txr/txr-manpage.html  Look for "Appendix A" in the table of contents, and there is a link to "Example: Matching C Language Comments".)

C-style comments can include the sequence `/*` in the interior, such that `/*/**/` is a valid comment. The closest `*/` terminates the comment so that `/* */aaa/* */` is two comments with `aaa` in between, not one comment. This "non-greedy" behavior complicates the matching in a regex language which has no non-greedy operator.